# How to say "hard working person" in japanese

Tags: translation, meaning

I am preparing Japanese resume and i want to mention my skills in 特技。Is “勤勉”　a correct word to say that i am  hard working???

Comment: note "real Japanese resumes" are different that "Japanese translations of English resumes". One thing I remember is you must put a passport-sized photo on the top-right, and the paper size needs to be a4. The "theme" is different from a USA-style. I cannot remember more than that. I'd recommend an English resume, Japanese translation of English resume, a "real" Japanese resume, and a personal "meishi" even if a student (English one side / Japanese the other) for a good first impression "meishi-kokan".

Comment: As far as a 履歴書 is concerned, I wouldn't consider 'hard-working' to be a 'special skill', more a personality trait or a work ethic.

Comment: You can use 努力家 (I don't know if it's fit for a resume though)
I would double check with actual Japanese resume examples to make sure you're heading in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes 勤勉 is a common na-adjective that means "hardworking", and you can consider using it in the 自己アピール/自己紹介 section (or something with a similar name).

However, it usually does not count as your 特技 because 特技 refers to some uncommon/special ability. Writing just 勤勉であること or 努力できること in the 特技 section might look as if you were a boring hobbyless person. In your case, probably you can list at least 英語 as your 特技. You can list your other abilities/hobbies such as 野球, 料理, プログラミング, 数学 or whatever that may interest the interviewer. (Well, if you can add some interesting episode that can prove your outstanding hardworking-ness, 勤勉さ or 集中力 might count as your 特技...)